How do I join a meta site? Where is the "Join this community" button?
I've been on the Ask Different site for 8 years, that is where my most activity is. I want to be able to ask questions on Meta but I don't see how to join.

You don't have to join, the account on a per-site meta is a "sub account" of the main, and derived from it, it's created together. The only exception is this very site (Meta Stack Exchange) which you have to join like any other SE main site. (Which you did already if you were able to post. :))

If you already have an account on Ask Different, and have at least 5 reputation there (which you do), then you can ask a question like you would on any Stack Exchange site, using the Ask Question button. If you don't have 5 reputation on that site, you can still ask on Meta if its related to your own question (and you have to give the question URL when asking).
